# Parse JSON via Codable protocol

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have an answer with Firebase in this form:

```
    ["allNews": <__NSArrayM 0x6000015f06c0>(
{
    createDate = "21.02.19";
    creator = "lol@gmail.com";
    creatorImageURL = "<null>";
    creatorUID = kzorlyIOI3RgEjCV1XDLQUhu5CS2;
    newsImageURL = "";
    text = "Daft g s dfg ";
    title = "Test ";
},
{
    createDate = "21.02.19";
    creator = "plol2@gmail.com";
    creatorImageURL = "<null>";
    creatorUID = Tw1JzFzcVbelRUA7GoFZ9CIWIwr1;
    newsImageURL = "";
    text = Vcbccvbvb;
    title = hdbdvbccfb;
}
)
]
```

How can I parse it via the Codable protocol?

Below is my code:

```
struct AllNews: Codable {
    var allNews: [DetailNews]
}

struct DetailNews: Codable {
    var creator: String
    var creatorUID: String
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var createDate: String
    var creatorImageURL: String
    var newsImageURL: String
}
```

that's how I parse the data

```
guard let newsData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: document.data(), options: []) else { return }
let decodeJSON = JSONDecoder()

let allNews = try? decodeJSON.decode([DetailNews].self, from: newsData)
print(allNews)
```

but all the same allNews comes nil although the news data comes to me in the form of json which is attached above

Comment: What's the error message that you're getting here? Also add code where you parse using JSON Decoder

Comment: paste your JSON in here and it will attempt to do it for you https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift

Comment: creatorImageURL and newsImageURL needs to be optional `String?`

Comment: **Never ever ignore `Decoding` errors**. `catch` the error, read the descriptive error message and fix it immediately.

Comment: catch the error as I've done in the answer and post its output

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving response in format:

```
[ "allNews": (
    {
        key : value
    },
    {
        key : value
    }
)]
```

As your news array lies in allNews key so you should pass `AllNews` struct to decode your response as:

```
guard let newsData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: document.data(), options: []) else { return }
let allNews = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AllNews.self, from: newsData)
print(allNews)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help you parse your data

```
let value = response.data

do {
    let allValues = try JSONDecoder().decode([DetailNews].self, from: value)
} catch let error {
     print(error)
}
```

Make sure value is of type Data

Comment: Why the downvote? The guy clearly asked(before edits) 'How can I parse it via the Codable protocol?'. The answer tells you how to parse using Codable Protocol